# Joint Probability Density of correlated uniform random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, correlation

let X and Y be two continuous random variables with uniform distribution in the same interval [a;b].

They are correlated with a given correlation coefficient $\rho$.

I'm curious if there is the analytical opportunity to evaluate the joint probability density $f(x,y)$.

It is equal to $f(x,y) = f(x)\cdot f(y|x)$ but suppose $f(y|x)$ is unknown.

There are similar questions but:

- many of them (for instance [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2546161/find-correlation-given-conditional-probability-of-joint-normal), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2546161/find-correlation-given-conditional-probability-of-joint-normal)) refer to the standard distribution
- others tell that knowing $\rho$ is not sufficient to find the conditional probability density

Well, if it is true, I wanted to know which is the missing information and understand why $\rho$ is not sufficient. Maybe, there is the opportunity to estimate the missing part. Or maybe there exists some specific properties of the uniform distribution.

Comment: It is not sufficient roughly speaking because correlation is only a measure of linear dependence. It is sufficient in the case that $X,Y$ are jointly normal. One can find examples of variables that have zero correlation but are not independent.

Comment: You need to learn about [copulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)).

Comment: @g g I'm going to take a look. Just a question (since it seems a quite complex topic for a newbie like me): what can I get with copulas? Is it sufficient to get the conditional density? Does it allow me get the joint moments?